# How to create multiple dialog boxes with wx python and how to close all of them at once

Tags: python, random, wxpython

How would be able to open lets say 5 dialog boxes and have the last one open close all the dialog boxes.

Comment: I think you'd have to use multi threading for that to work. Check out the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Each dialog will have to open the next dialog since dialogs tend to block the main loop when shown modally. You could use PubSub to send a message in the closing event of the last dialog to the previous dialog that it too should close and do the same thing in that dialog and so forth. Each dialog emits a message to its parent to close too.

Here's a PubSub tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/